# How to make sure my code runs in GPU and not CPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I am new to deep learning and tensorflow. I have a following code. Whenever I run this code my system administrator notifies me that my code is running in CPU and not GPU even thought we have GPU in the system and I have only installed tensorflow-gpu. What changes should I make to my code so that it runs in GPU and not CPU?

```
import math
import tempfile

import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Conv2D, Dense, Flatten, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential

import fastestimator as fe
from fastestimator.dataset.data import cifair10
from fastestimator.architecture.tensorflow import WideResidualNetwork
from fastestimator.op.numpyop.meta import Sometimes
from fastestimator.op.numpyop.multivariate import HorizontalFlip, PadIfNeeded, RandomCrop
from fastestimator.op.numpyop.univariate import CoarseDropout, Normalize
from fastestimator.op.tensorop.loss import CrossEntropy, SuperLoss
from fastestimator.op.tensorop.model import ModelOp, UpdateOp
from fastestimator.trace.io import BestModelSaver
from fastestimator.trace.metric import MCC, Accuracy
from fastestimator.trace.xai import LabelTracker

#training parameters
epochs = 100
batch_size = 128
max_train_steps_per_epoch = None
max_eval_steps_per_epoch = None
save_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()

train_data, eval_data = cifair10.load_data()
test_data = eval_data.split(0.5)

def corrupt_dataset(dataset, n_classes=10, corruption_fraction=0.4):
    # Keep track of which samples were corrupted for visualization later
    corrupted = [0 for _ in range(len(dataset))]
    # Perform the actual label corruption

    n_samples_per_class = len(dataset) // n_classes # dataset size 50000
    # n_classes - 100
    # n_samples_per_class - 500
    n_to_corrupt_per_class = math.floor(corruption_fraction * n_samples_per_class) # 200
    n_corrupted = [0] * n_classes
    i = 0

    while any([elem < n_to_corrupt_per_class for elem in n_corrupted]): # while any class is left to be corrupted
        current_class = dataset[i]['y'].item()
        if n_corrupted[current_class] < n_to_corrupt_per_class: #check the number of corrupted data of a particular class has reached 200 or not
            dataset[i]['y'] = (dataset[i]['y'] + np.random.randint(1, n_classes)) % n_classes # change the y value of a dataset
            n_corrupted[current_class] += 1
            corrupted[i] = 1
        i += 1
    # Put the corruption labels into the dataset for visualization
    dataset['data_labels'] = np.array(corrupted, dtype=np.int).reshape((len(dataset), 1))

corrupt_dataset(train_data)

def get_wrn():
    return WideResidualNetwork((32, 32, 3))

def build_estimator(loss_op):
    pipeline = fe.Pipeline(train_data=train_data,
                           eval_data=eval_data,
                           test_data=test_data,
                           batch_size=batch_size,
                           ops=[Normalize(inputs="x", outputs="x", mean=(0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4465), std=(0.2471, 0.2435, 0.2616)),
                                PadIfNeeded(min_height=40, min_width=40, image_in="x", image_out="x", mode="train"),
                                RandomCrop(32, 32, image_in="x", image_out="x", mode="train"),
                                Sometimes(HorizontalFlip(image_in="x", image_out="x", mode="train")),
                                CoarseDropout(inputs="x", outputs="x", max_holes=1, mode="train"),
                                ])
    model = fe.build(model_fn=get_wrn, optimizer_fn='adam')
    network = fe.Network(ops=[
        ModelOp(model=model, inputs="x", outputs="y_pred"),
        loss_op,  # <<<----------------------------- This is where the secret sauce will go
        UpdateOp(model=model, loss_name="ce")
    ])
    traces = [
        Accuracy(true_key="y", pred_key="y_pred"),
        MCC(true_key="y", pred_key="y_pred"),
        BestModelSaver(model=model, save_dir=save_dir, metric="mcc", save_best_mode="max", load_best_final=True),
        # We will also visualize the difference between the normal and corrupted image confidence scores. You could follow this with an
        # ImageViewer trace, but we will get the data out of the system summary instead later for viewing.
        LabelTracker(metric="confidence", label="data_labels", label_mapping={"Normal": 0, "Corrupted": 1}, mode="train", outputs="label_confidence"),
    ]
    estimator = fe.Estimator(pipeline=pipeline,
                             network=network,
                             epochs=epochs,
                             traces=traces,
                             train_steps_per_epoch=max_train_steps_per_epoch,
                             eval_steps_per_epoch=max_eval_steps_per_epoch,
                             log_steps=300)
    return estimator

loss = SuperLoss(CrossEntropy(inputs=("y_pred", "y"), outputs="ce"), output_confidence="confidence")  # The output_confidence arg is only needed if you want to visualize
estimator_super = build_estimator(loss)
superL = estimator_super.fit("SuperLoss")

print("before test")
summary = estimator_super.test()
print("after test")
print(summary.history["test"])
```

Comment: How is the code actually being ran?

Comment: Might this help?  - https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/solution-to-tensorflow-2-not-using-gpu-119fb3e04daa - My guess is that the answer to your question very much depends on what other modules you have installed and how your environment is otherwise configured.

Comment: First I activate conda. Then I run python3 filename.py.

Comment: @CryptoFool let me run it. I'll let you know the result.